# Ruby on Rails using a model method breaks my URIs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and am doing something wrong with my model methods that I can't figure out. In the model, it accepts a url from the user and then scrapes that url for an image and a title. Everything works fine if I hardcode a value in from some random website, but if I get the value from the link the user submits, I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: let!(:list_link){FactoryGirl.create(:list_link, list: list)}
 URI::InvalidURIError:
   bad URI(is not URI?): http://list link
```

My best guess is that the method is mutating the database data, which I do not want it to do. I'm trying to use the link to generate 2 extra attributes of list_link.title and list_link.image. I've tried cloning the original link, but that doesn't seem to work.

Here's the model:

```
class ListLink < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :list

validates :link_url, presence: true
validates :list_id, presence: true

before_save :set_link
def set_link
    self.link_url = link_url
    link_info = OpenGraph.fetch(link_url.clone)
    if link_info
        self.title = link_info.title
        self.image_url = link_info.image
    end
end
```

end

Here's my factory:

```
    FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :list_link do
    link_url "list link"
    image_url "image"
    title "title"
    list
  end
end
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: where you defined `link_url`?

Comment: Why are you resetting `link_url` in `set_link`? What does your factory look like?

Comment: it's a column in the database. I changed the name from link to link_url as it seemed to be causing some problems - not sure if thats the reason for these issues. I'll post the factory above.

Comment: I reset link_url in the method because I've been trying many different iterations of that method. I've been trying to get a cloned object for the link_url so I could scrap it with opengraph, but every time I run the clone through opengraph it seems to upset the original link_url and all link_to paths using it

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I solved it, was the plugin gem throwing all the errors, not the rails links. Thanks for the comments!